# Two controls side by side design in XML android

Tags: android, xml

This is my image.xml file

[image]

You can see "New Text", a TextView below a Price in Item1 box. I want that TextView exactly beside that price.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/middleLeft"
        android:background="#E8F5E9"
        android:layout_below="@id/topPanel"
        android:layout_marginRight="190dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item 1"
            android:id="@+id/txtItem1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:editable="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etPrice1"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtItem1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtCheapestItem"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtCheapestItem" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtItem1Cur"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPrice1"
            android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/txtItem1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
           />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/etVolume1"
            android:hint="Volume"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etPrice1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etPrice1"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPrice1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In fact I want that kind of design beside every Price and Volume. But just help me for one. I will do it for others.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh I couldn't upload an image. Will anyone help me without it?

Comment: Add android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" in TextView.

Comment: @Purvi image code edited

Comment: No. Its not working. It is moving from left side. I want it exact beside 1st EditText i.e. etPrice1.

Comment: add the editText and Text View in Horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: @Purvi Do you want TextView left to EditText?

Comment: @Mrunal Right to EditText

Comment: @PradeepGupta. Thank you. You are right. I have to add separate <LinearLayout> for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use RelativeLayout

Try it!!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/middleLeft"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/topPanel"
android:layout_marginRight="190dp"
android:background="#E8F5E9"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtItem1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:text="Item 1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPrice1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtItem1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Price"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItem1Cur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/etPrice1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etPrice1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etVolume1"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPrice1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Volume"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow !! Amazing. Its working.I tried it before but was not worked. I copied your code and its perfect. Thanks a lot. !!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPrice1"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtItem1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtCheapestItem"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtCheapestItem" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtItem1Cur"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPrice1"
        android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/txtItem1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an answer. It will become too long. But there is no other option I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPrice1"
    android:hint="Price"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtItem1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtCheapestItem"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtCheapestItem" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtItem1Cur"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPrice1"
    android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/txtItem1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. Got an answer. Exactly I have to do this.